# How to navigate forward through the code?

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

In the VBE code window you can go to the last visited position in your code via

- `CTRL+SHIFT+F2`

There doesn't seem to be a way to go forward again so that you can navigate back and forth. Or is there?

[Code Window Navigation Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/code-window-navigation-keys)

Comment: You can add bookmarks and navigate through them, but I guess this isn't what you need?

Comment: @AntiDrondert No. But how do you add bookmarks and navigate to them?

Comment: Shift+F2 takes you to the definition, which is where you seem to have been if Ctrl+Shift+F2 took you back

Comment: @Roland *View* -> *Toolbars* -> *Edit* (ticked), *Toggle bookmark*,*Next bookmark*,*Previous bookmark*,*Clear all bookmarks* are right after *Uncomment block* (I'm using realy old version of excel, so it might be somewhere else for you)

Comment: @AntiDrondert Same thing in Excel 2016.

Comment: Try Alt+F4, will take you where you need to go.